# Privileges right error when re-attaching a detached database

Tags: sql-server

I detached a SQL Server database for moving the files (both data and log) to another computer. When I tried to re-attach the files, I get this message:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
>   Cannot access the specified path or file on the server. Verify that you have the necessary security privileges that the path or file exists.

I added "full control right" to my security privileges on the folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server`. However it failed for some subfolders.

Then I tried adding "everyone" and assigned it with "full control right" without any fails. But the same message still persisted.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the path is correct, as it changes from version to version. Then add rights to the service account used by SQL Server. Also make sure to be checking the correct computer, meaning that you should be handling the files, folders and permissions in the server not your client computer.

Comment: I am working on the Windows Server 2016, not other computers. I am sure that the data file being attached is in the folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA. The message says I have no right in this folder (DATA). I have tried logging on as Administrator, but also failed. Can you give me other hints?

Comment: It´s not your login, it's the account used by SQL Server service.

Comment: I have added MSSQLSERVER in the user list and assign it with the full control right.Howerver still failed.